# Can't access the images in server1 from server2 on SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Server1 has the images. Server2 has the SSRS report.

In Server1 the images were stored in a folder named images.

I have added the imageURL as 'Server1/images/image1.png' on the Server2 SSRS report, but the images never appeared in the preview.

What might be the issue. How to resolve this.please help on this out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realistically there are three possibilities:

1. The images do not exist in the folder; the folder is called something else; the images are called something else.
2. The account running SSRS does not have permission to view the images.
3. You are trying to access the images incorrectly - e.g. windows shares not set up correctly or being referenced correctly.

Further, you should look in the [SSRS Logs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157403.aspx) to find the exact error message.

Comment: yeah thanks bro...I solved the issue but now i need to merge the shared folder URL with parameter value in ssrs report. I tried some thing like this"file://X1/Logos/" +Parameters!LogoFile.Value. The actual value for this  is file://X1/Logos/defaultLogo.jpg. but it gets printed as "defaultLogo.jpg" not showing image in SSRS report. how to solve this.

Comment: Show me a screenshot of your expression please

Comment: Thanks for your help bro,
Now I having some other issue,
PC1 having the images. PC2 has the SSRS report.
In PC1 the images were stored in a folder named "company".
I give shared Permission for PC1 folder.Then run the SSRS report image expression as "file://PC1/CompanyLogos/" +Parameters!LogoFile.Value".
It shows image in  SSRS report in preview.

Comment: But If I put the code in IIS and Give credential details for execution account in "sql server reporting services"  with pc1 credential details.Then I run the report through page,it throws the error.
"The report server has encountered a configuration error. Logon failed for the unattended execution account. (rsServerConfigurationError)".
what might be the issue, How to resolve it.

Comment: If you post your **new** question separately then you will probably get lot's of help. Many people won't be reading this now as it is not new?